# Currency conversion for paypal

Tags: ubercart, payment-gateways

I have integrated paypal payment using the [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) 7.x-3.6 module in my website.

My store currency is Rs(INR). Now I have 1500 Rs in a cart When I am proceeding to checkout on paypal its showing 1500 USD.

Isn't it possible that the amount converts in equivalent USD automatically?

If not, then how can I convert it from INR to USD?

Comment: Hi, I have stumbled upon this issue today. How did you managed this ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out. It is a workaround for converting the currency on checkout https://www.drupal.org/node/789284